# Strange C ++ behavior when i using a template in which need to calculate the address of an array cell

Tags: c++, templates

I created a matrix class and for example a simple cleanup function

```
template<typename T>
class matrix
{
public:
    matrix(int Lenght, int Height)
    {
        this->container = new T[this->lenght * this->height];

        this->lenght = Lenght;
        this->height = Height;
    }

    void Nulling()
    {
        size_t A = sizeof(T);
        for (int i = 0; i < (this->height * this->lenght); i++)
        {
           this->container)[i] = 0;
           //((T*)this->container)[i] = 0;    // same result
        }
    }


    T* container = nullptr; 
    int lenght; 
    int height; 

};
```

when i == 100226, debugging stops and an error occurs while writing ( i have 512*512 matrix so its 262144 elements)

I think problem is incorrect calculating adress with templates, i try this construction

```
size_t A = sizeof(T);
        for (int i = 0; i < (this->height * this->lenght); i++)
        {
            this->container[0] = 0;
            this->container += A;
        }
```

its cause error on i == 12529

So i dont know what to do now.

Comment: In `matrix` constructor, you use `this->lenght` and `this->height` before you actually assign values to them. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized variables.

Comment: On a side note, your class does not follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), so you will run into more problems later. You are missing a destructor to free the array, and copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators to copy/move the array around.

Comment: It is weird that you know array, template, how to debug, but miss [this tiny piece of knowledge (cppreference link)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members).   See "Member initialization" section.

Comment: oh omg it was stuped..... But why then always 100226 .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor, the statement

```
this->container = new T[this->lenght * this->height];
```

Has **undefined behavior**, because you are using `this->lenght` and `this->height` before they have been assigned values, thus the size of the allocated array is *indeterminate*. You need to do those assignments first:

```
matrix(int Lenght, int Height)
{
    this->lenght = Lenght;
    this->height = Height;
    this->container = new T[this->lenght * this->height];
}
```

Alternatively, use the input values instead of the class members when allocating the array:

```
matrix(int Lenght, int Height)
{
    this->container = new T[Lenght * Height];
    this->lenght = Lenght;
    this->height = Height;
}
```